# How to get around "connection to ui timed out"?

Tags: android, terminal-emulator

I'm developing on rooted Android phone and need to execute few commands. `su` or `su -c` command gives me `connection to ui timed out`. Root privileges are granted to terminal emulator in settings.

What I can do ?

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered an issue like this. In my case it was that the app that is responsible for the allow/deny popup wasn't installed. `su` was installed, just not the GUI counterpart.
Make sure it's the same version as whatever provided `su`.